# Remove :first-child from sidebar of titles when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've wrote a script that appends a div to a sidebar when an article is scrolled to on the page, the div simply contains the title of the article that is loaded in. This is a part of an infinite scroll functionality that I have been building for a news website.

The issue I have ran into during testing is; when the user scrolls to an article quite far down the page, my sidebar begins to contain a lot of titles, so I'm looking to eliminate the `:first-child` when the sidebar contains 10 child divs (titles).

**jQuery:**

```
if(($('#sideArticles').children().size()) > 10){
var del = $('#sideArticles').find(':first-child');
$('#sideArticles').remove(del);
}
```

Nothing is happening, nor am I receiving any errors from the console. If anyone could shed some knowledge that'd be much appreciated.

Cheers, Rich.

Comment: `del.remove()` - did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this:

```
if(($('#sideArticles').children().size()) > 10){
    var del = $('#sideArticles').children().eq(0);
    del.remove();
}
```

Comment: This worked a treat, thanks man. I'll be able to accept the answer in a minute.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you ;) !

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough code to really do testes but this could work :

```
if(($('#sideArticles').children().size()) > 10){
    var del = $('#sideArticles').children().eq(0);
    del.remove();
}
```